# Why getting a key value changed it's data type in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, companion-object

So I have class named Bidding.kt, and I have companion object in that class to be passed to the MainActivity.kt class. Also I have a function that returns as int value.

```
companion object {
    const val bidInputKey = "bidInput"
}

val bidInput = returningBid() //this function returns an int value
val returnIntent = Intent().apply {
    putExtra(bidInputKey, bidInput)
}
```

In the MainActivity.kt class, when I called the bidInput to be assigned to a new variable and passed it into a class's parameter, it required to be converted to Int (I set the class's parameter data type as Int). I don't understand why it changed the data type and detect it as a String, I declare it as Int on Bidding class.

```
    class openBid(var input: Int) {
        //doing some stuff here
    }
    val puttingBid = Bidding.bidInputKey
    val addBid = openBid(puttingBid) // I get error in this line because 
                                    // puttingBid is detected as a String, not Int
```

I can avoid the error by adding .toInt() when declaring puttingBid, but I want to know why the data type is changed by itself.

Comment: This may help you. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: `val puttingBid = Bidding.bidInputKey` with this statement `puttingBid` has as String value because `bidInputKey` is a String . Why u think it should be an Int ?

Comment: This question is all over the place. The string `Bidding.bidInputKey` has a value of `"bidInput"` - you cannot convert that to an integer. I assume you want to call `Bidding.returningBid()` instead of `Bidding.bidInputKey`? Or maybe you need to get it from the activity intent extras - you haven't provided enough detail here to know what it is you are trying to do. Do you use the `returnIntent` to launch a second activity, then you want to retrieve the integer value in that second activity?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to pass that `Int` to `MainActivity` as an extra on the `Intent`, you need to pull that value out of the extras, same as how you put it in:

```
val puttingBid = intent.getIntExtra(Bidding.bidInputKey, DEFAULT_VALUE_IF_MISSING)
```

All `bidInputKey` is is an identifier string, used to store a value in the `Intent` and then retrieve it later. There's nothing magical about it that would make it fetch the `Int` itself or anything! You need to do that yourself.

Comment: @PleaseDon'tBanMe it only uses the default value if there's no *IntExtra* in the `intent` with that key. And `intent` (aka `getIntent()`) is the `Intent` that was used to *start* the `Activity`. So if that Activity is being started a different way (not by you building that Intent and calling `startActivity`) it won't have that info. If you're doing that from *inside the Activity itself* and a new Activity isn't started, the value of `intent` won't change - see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, it might be easier to learn how to use `ViewModel`s to share state around your app: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?hl=en Those do rely on a single-activity design though. You could also store your data in something like `SharedPreferences` or a `DataStore` so `MainActivity` can just pull out the last-stored value, rather than relying on actively passing some state between components while the app is running. Hard to give any concrete advice without knowing exactly what you're doing here!